# Relation between holomorphic and harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I am getting wrong answer. So, I am looking for the right argument in this question.

> Let  f be a real valued harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ . Define the functions

g=  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ -i $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$,
$h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ +i $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Then which of $g$ and $h$ is holomorphic function?

Answer:

> g is holomorphic , but f is not

I thought of using the result that if f is a harmonic function then there exists an holomorphic function whose real part is f and a holomorphic function whose imagenary part is f but I can't be sure which is that holomorphic function so it cant be used. I can't think of any other result other than this.

Background:I have studied about harmonic function sfrom ponnusamy silvermann .

Kindly help!!

Comment: Ar you familiar with Cauchy Riemann equations? The answer to this question is straightforward if you use the charatctrization of holomorphic functions using Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: My guess is that the question actually was “Then are which of $g$ and $h$ holomorphic functions?”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Which among g and h would be holomorphic?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you please elaborate it ? I am not getting it!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I still don't get it . I am confused. Do you mind adding an answer?